# yfinance API incorrect historical data

Tags: python, yfinance

I want to use yfinace to build a historical stock database to test some strategies. No i came across a problem with some historical data while using the api. It mainly happens for stocks which are not traded not a US market.

For example if I get the historical data for 'BOE.L' using:

```
boel = yf.Ticker("BOE.L")
boelHist = boel.history(period='max')
```

The earliest Close price returned is for 2001-06-11, which is: **2.191053e-06**
While, on the yahoo website, this value is: **2,347.00** (for this date)

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Observed similar behaviour with share 'SAP.DE'.

```
ticker = yf.Ticker("SAP.DE")
hist = ticker.history(start="2019-04-16", end="2021-04-16")
```

Going back e.g. the last 2 years from now (2021-04-16), the prices seems to be correct until dividends are payed.
In this case, dividends have been payed on 2020-05-22 (1,58), 2020-05-21 (1,58) and 2019-05-15 (1,50).
The difference correlates almost (but not 100%) to the amount of the dividend.

Following screenshot is showing the differences with the "Open" prices:

[comparison yfinance - yahoo - SAP.DE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKnoZ.png)

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SAP.DE/history?period1=1514764800&period2=1618617600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true

You can observe the difference for "Open", "High", "Low" and "Close*", but "Adj Close**" seems to be correct.

[comparsion 2 - SAP.DE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhRu8.png)

If you use parameter *interval="1h"*, the "Open" price (108,36) is correct (2020-05-21):

```
hist = ticker.history(interval="1h", start="2020-05-19", end="2020-05-25")
```

2020-05-21  **108.360001**  108.360001  107.599998  107.739998   175957
2020-05-21  107.900002  108.040001  107.300003  107.680000   416473
2020-05-21  107.459999  107.839996  107.300003  107.400002   433919
2020-05-21  107.580002  107.639999  107.120003  107.300003   158440
2020-05-21  107.480003  107.559998  107.059998  107.320000   227438
2020-05-21  107.379997  108.019997  107.199997  107.739998   189142
2020-05-21  107.500000  108.339996  107.500000  107.879997   336406
2020-05-21  108.059998  108.339996  107.120003  107.279999   454079
2020-05-21  107.779999  107.779999  106.400002  106.720001   542355

Maybe the following can explain the differences:

1.) Calculation of Adjusted Close:
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28256.html

2.)
Source: https://finance.zacks.com/adjusted-closing-price-vs-closing-price-9991.html

*"While dividends are good for stockholders, they actually decrease the value of each company stock.
The decrease is caused by the fact that paying out dividends reduces the value of the company because they are transferring money or stocks into the hands of shareholders instead of investing it back into the company. Unlike closing price, adjusted closing price reflects devaluation caused by dividend disbursement."*

Further discussion about this:

[How does Yahoo Finance calculate Adjusted Close stock prices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799567/how-does-yahoo-finance-calculate-adjusted-close-stock-prices)

Seems, that there is a parameter "back_adjust=True", which should provide adjusted values, but was not able to get adjustes values?

```
hist = ticker.history(interval="1d", start="2020-05-19", end="2020-05-23", back_adjust=True)
```

https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/687